How to preserve /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
In Ubuntu 24.04, netplan converts all of the files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections into a YAML file (in /etc/netplan/, and then deletes the original. That said, I wrote a script that synchronizes certain connection profiles with some non-Ubuntu computers, which do not have netplan. (And I have no intention of installing netplan, BTW.)
So, how can I tell netplan to leave this directory alone? Ideally, I wish I could remove netplan, but NetworkManager seems to depend on it. :-(
Is there a way to disable netplan, and only use NetworkManager?
PS: This problem occurs whenever NetworkManager gets an update (via a *.deb package, not snap).
